# How can i remove only the last bracket from a string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-2.7

How can i remove only the last bracket from a string ?

For example,
INPUT 1:

```
"hell(h)o(world)"
```

i want this result:

```
"hell(h)o"
```

Input 2 :-

```
hel(lo(wor)ld)
```

i want :-

```
hel
```

as you can see the middle brackets remain intact only the last bracket got removed.

I tried :-

```
import re
string = 'hell(h)o(world)' 
print(re.sub('[()]', '', string))
```

output :-

```
hellhoworld
```

i figured out a solution :-

i did it like this

```
string = 'hell(h)o(world)' 
if (string[-1] == ")"):
    add=int(string.rfind('(', 0))
    print(string[:add])
```

output :-

```
hell(h)o
```

looking for other optimised solutions/suggestions..

Comment: Please clarify your problem.  Your code above seems aimed at removing either a bracket or a parenthesis.  You also state that you want to remove the matching left enclosure.  What do you want to do with nested enclosures, such as `hel(lo(wor)ld)` ?
As others have noted, posting your attempt as an answer is inappropriate, especially as you've found it unsatisfying.

Comment: @Prune thanks for the above comment in case of  "hel(lo(wor)ld)" it will be "hel" since i want to remove the last bracket nested one will go along with it.

Comment: What about this "hell(h)o(world)blahblahblah" what is your output?

Comment: @Hamzawi in case of "hell(h)o(world)blahblahblah" it will be "hell(h)oblahblahblah"

Comment: Your code fails with this example and returns "hel(lo" , right?

Comment: yes @Hamzawi that is why i posted it here.

Comment: Could you please tell me based on what you said the output will be hel in hel(lo(wor)ld)?

Comment: sure @Hamzawi . i want to remove the last brackets from the string which is in this case will be the outer one i.e "(lo(wor)ld)" because of what only "hel" will be left.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the below if this is useful, Let me know I will optimize further.

```
string = 'hell(h)o(world)'
count=0
r=''
for i in reversed(string):
    if count <2 and (i == ')' or i=='('):
        count+=1
        pass
    else:
        r+=i
for i in reversed(r):
    print(i, end='')
```

Comment: the above code is not giving any output to me.

Comment: Hey Rahul, Where do you find error. I hope this should work. let me know the error will help you out

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the last bracket from the string even if it's not at the end of the string, you can try something like this. This will only work if you know you have a substring beginning and ending with parentheses somewhere in the string, so you may want to implement some sort of check for that. You will also need to modify if you are dealing with nested parenthesis.

```
str = "hell(h)o(world)"
r_str = str[::-1]    # creates reverse copy of string
for i in range(len(str)):
    if r_str[i] == ")":
        start = i
    elif r_str[i] == "(":
        end = i+1
        break
x = r_str[start:end][::-1]    # substring that we want to remove
str = str.replace(x,'')
print(str)
```

output:

`hell(h)o`

If the string is not at the end:

`str = "hell(h)o(world)blahblahblah"`

output:

`hell(h)oblahblahblah`

Edit: Here is a modified version to detect nested parenthesis. However, please keep in mind that this will not work if there are unbalanced parenthesis in the string.

```
str = "hell(h)o(w(orld))"
r_str = str[::-1]
p_count = 0
for i in range(len(str)):
    if r_str[i] == ")":
        if p_count == 0:
            start = i
        p_count = p_count+1
    elif r_str[i] == "(":
        if p_count == 1:
            end = i+1
            break
        else:
            p_count = p_count - 1
x = r_str[start:end][::-1]
print("x:", x)
str = str.replace(x,'')
print(str)
```

output:

`hell(h)o`

Comment: hello @jbowen4 for "hell(h)o(w(orld))" it is giving me "hell(h)o(w)" but i want something like "hell(h)o"

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
string = 'hell(h)o(w(orl)d)23'
new_str = ''
escaped = 0
for char in reversed(string):
    if escaped is not None and char == ')':
        escaped += 1

    if not escaped:
        new_str = char + new_str

    if escaped is not None and char == '(':
        escaped -= 1
        if escaped == 0:
            escaped = None

print(new_str)
```

This starts escaping when a `)` and stops when it's current level is closed with `(`.
So a nested `()` would not effect it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `re.sub('[()]', '', string)` will replace any parenthesis in the string with an empty string.

To match the last set of balanced parenthesis, and if you can make use of the regex [PyPi module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), you can use a recursive pattern repeating the first sub group, and assert that to the right there are no more occurrences of either `(` or `)`

```
(\((?:[^()\n]++|(?1))*\))(?=[^()\n]*$)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\(` Match `(`
  - `(?:[^()\n]++|(?1))*` Repeat 0+ times matching either any char except `(` `)` or a newline. If you do, recurse group 1 using `(?1)`
  - `\)` Match `)`
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?=[^()\n]*$)` Positive lookahead, assert till the end of the string no `(` or `)` or newline

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ffvif4/1) and a [Python demo](https://tio.run/##VY7BCsIwEETv@xVL8LDbFkG8FUo/pK3QYmwKMQlJRAX/PZZQRRcGlscwM@4ZlTXHlJarsz6il7N8AIToFzMHbLADXE8oqTUptnS3Xp9ZVF9MOkP@p7/mSY/qIwEDgBtjlN6s6V5QT9TW3Yl4KMsXtQfmomemtsms2LEAuFiPAReD264697j1j5QX78Ntoi22QiEqDMwpvQE).

For example

```
import regex

strings = [
    "hell(h)o(world)",
    "hel(lo(wor)ld)",
    "hell(h)o(world)blahblahblah"
]

pattern = r"(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))(?=[^()]*$)"

for s in strings:
    print(regex.sub(pattern, "", s))
```

Output

```
hell(h)o
hel
hell(h)oblahblahblah
```